# Angular controller doesn't work correctly

Tags: angularjs

i'm trying to set up a simple angular project, but, in the moment when the angular controller should be initialized, don't work...

The /home route is working (or i think so, beacause the template is showing)
but, the ng-repeat is "commented" in the output code.

this is my main.js:

```
(function()
{

    angular.module('angularTest',['ngRoute'])
    .config(config)

    config.$inject=['$routeProvider'];  
    function config($routeProvider)
    {
            $routeProvider
            .when('/home', {
            templateUrl : '/home',
            controller  : HomeCtrl
        });

    }

    HomeCtrl.$inject=['$scope'];
    function HomeCtrl($scope)
    {   console.log('homectrl');
        $scope.init = init;

        function init()
        {

            $scope.names=['a','b','c'];
        }
        $scope.init();
    }

})()
```

server.js

```
var express     = require('express');  
var app         = express();  
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
var http        = require('http');
var path        = require('path');


var home    = require('./app/routes/views/homeRoute');




app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'app/views'));
app.set('view engine','pug');


app.use(home);

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
app.set('port',process.env.PORT || 8080);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'),function()
{
    console.log('listening '+app.get('port'));
});
```

Here my home.pug

```
html(ng-app='angularTest')
    head
        body
            h1(ng-repeat='name in names')
script(src='/libs/angular/angular.min.js')
script(src='/libs/angular/angular-route.min.js')
script(src='/libs/angular/angular-sanitize.min.js')
script(src='/js/main.js')
```

and the output

```
<html ng-app="angularTest" class="ng-scope">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body><!-- ngRepeat: name in names -->
        <script src="/libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/libs/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/libs/angular/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

homeRoute.js

```
var router=require('express').Router();


router.get('/home',function(req, res) 
{

    res.render('_shared/home.pug');

});

module.exports=router;
```

Complete code: https://github.com/federhico/AngularTest

Answer (score 0):

templateUrl  in `$routeProvider` should be like this, appended with `.html`, also check if the path is right,

Place the controller with `''`

```
 function config($routeProvider)
    {
            $routeProvider
            .when('/home', {
            templateUrl : '/home.html',
            controller  : 'HomeCtrl'
        });

    }
```

Comment: No changes... the route go to a homeroute.js

I dont know how edit the post to add the file but if you look in the github is in AngularTest/app/routes/views/homeRoute.js

Comment: i can't , you can clone the repo ?